# What does the little dot at the sidebar means after hide "Document Outline"? [Image Included]

Tags: xcode, xcode6

In **Xcode 6.0.1**, after creation of project, there is no little dot beside *Main Window* and *Main Menu* icon with hide document outline. However, once I clicked the icon with no dot, the dot will appear and stick there. I have tried to save the `.nib` file and it is still there, so that is not the saving state of object(s).

What does that dot means? For what the dot is, please refer to the image below.

Thank you.

[image: Image01]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot indicates which objects are rendered in the main editor area (canvas) of IB. Selecting any visual object that isn't currently on the canvas adds it to the canvas so you can see it. That adds the dot. You can click the 'x' close button on any given object to remove it from the canvas. That removes the dot.

Comment: Could you tell me how to you know this? How to find solution for this kind of problem  next time? Thank you. @KenThomases

Comment: It was just a guess and then I checked it in Xcode. I always use the outline view of the document contents, so I really wasn't familiar with that dot until I saw your question.